# Stop the test once failure occurs in async test in xctest

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, async-await, xctest

How can I make sure my async test does not continues once assert is failed? After doing some research I understand I have to use `@MainActor` and `async` to make sure my restAPI set running in sequence. However, in my case I do not want the test continues once the assertion is failed. but How can I do it?

```
    @MainActor func testAsync() async throws {
        XCTAssert(false)
        print("xxxxxxx")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike every other unit test framework in existence, the default behavior on a failing assertion in XCTest is to continue the test.

But you can change this with:

```swift
continueAfterFailure = false
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/1496260-continueafterfailure

Comment: `continueAfterFailure = false` does not appear to behave correctly in `async` test methods.

Comment: Yikes. Let's see if they fix this in the coming release.